# Entry is not Clearing with Bindable Property

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My 2 Entries is binded from a bindable property and working well but after saving the data from Entries i want to clear Entries value but this could not able to effect on my UI ,if i i use ctrl+ save on my xaml file the onproperty changed event fired and Entries clears. Also i have used a class in my bindable property with two get set variables. if i create seprate two diffrent bindable properties for two entries than it works but in a class it does not works .but i want use only single bindable property with class. I am sharing my code.

//Inotify class

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
if (PropertyChanged != null)
{
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
else
{
return;
}
}
}
```

// model class

```
public class NoModel
{
public string No { get; set; }
public string Amt { get; set; }
}
```

//on property change event

```
public NoModel bindNoModel= new NoModel ();

public NoModel BindNoModel
{
get { return bindNoModel; }
set
{
bindNoModel= value;
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BindNoModel));
}
}
```

//my xaml code

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
        <Label WidthRequest="110" Text="Amount" VerticalOptions="Center" Font="Bold" FontSize="Medium" ></Label>
        <Entry Text="{Binding BindNoModel.Amt }" Placeholder="Enter Amount" ReturnType="Done"  ReturnCommand="{Binding SubmitCommand}" Keyboard="Numeric" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
```

//on save command

```
BindNoModel.No = string.Empty;
BindNoModel.Amt = string.Empty;
```

Note1 : Above code on save command does not work unitl i use ctrl +save on my xaml file and then UI changes.

Note 2 : This below code work if i create diffent properties

```
public string no;
public string No
{
    get { return no; }
    set
    {
        no = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(No));
    }
}
public string amt ;
public string Amt
{
get { return amt ; }
set
{
amt = value;
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Amt ));
}
}
```

//on save command

```
No = string.Empty;
Amt = string.Empty;
```

Comment: Your `NoModel` should inherit `INotifyPropertyChanged` and implement `PropertyChanged` handler. Note 2 is the correct way to define the properties in `NoModel` class. I hope Ctrl + Save reloads the UI is it in Debug mode which is HotReload a recent feature in Xamarin.

Comment: If i use Note-2 method then if i have 10 entries than i have to create 10 o property change event .

Comment: No, there's just one OnPropertyChangedEvent, you can place a break point and do a switch-case check to see which property is being changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original question, in the save command, you are changing the value of property `BindNoModel.No`, `BindNoModel.Amt` instead if `BindNoModel`, so the `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BindNoModel))` won't triggered.

You can reset the BindNoModel in the save command to achieve what you want:

```
public void save() {

    BindNoModel = new NoModel() {Amt = string.Empty };

}
```

In your Note2, you are changing the value of `BindNoModel.No` and `BindNoModel.Amy`, then the `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(No));` and `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Amy));` will be triggered so the value of entry changed:

```
public void save() {

    BindNoModel.No = string.Empty;
    BindNoModel.Amt = string.Empty;
}
```

A [sample project](https://github.com/XfHua/Data-Binding-test) has been uploaded and feel free to ask me any question.